# How to open edmx? Where to get LINQ to Entities?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, edmx, edmx-designer

After Visual Studio 2013 reinstall I can't open / create edmx files

So I think I should download LINQ to Entities somewhere because I already used to try a lot of Entity related stuff...

Where can I get edmx designer for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Run devenv.exe with the /resetskippkgs option from a command prompt once...

Comment: @KristoferA didn't help :(

Comment: Double-check the target .net framework version for your project so it is not 2.0 or something..(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link to the **Entity Framework 6.0.2 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013**:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762#

### Edit:

- **Right-click** on your project, select **Add**, select **New Item...**

[image: Add new item]

- Select **Data** from the left pane, select **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, click **Add*

[image: Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model]

- Select **Empty Model** and then click **Finish**

[image: Select empty model]

This should bring you to the Entity Data Model Designer where you can drag and drop entities and create relationships.

Comment: Yes, I used to find it and already got installed, so I can create tt files but still can't create or open `edmx` ...

Comment: Here's a blog on the ways to use the entity framework within Visual Studio 2013, it looks like you'll want to do `Database First`: http://henry416.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/entity-framework-6-and-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how it should help me, possibly my VS installation just broken with some reason

Comment: I misspoke, you'll want to do the `Model First` approach. I'll update my answer to reflect the steps on how to do so.

Comment: You still don't get me... There is not "Entity Data Model" in list

Comment: Nope, I didn't understand that. Have you tried finding `Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio 2013` in Programs and Features and running a repair on it?

Comment: Repair really helped :)